# Suddenly no sound on Debian Stretch?

Tags: linux, debian, audio, alsa

After a fresh Win10 installation on a 2nd SSD my speakers on Debian 9 aren't working anymore. Before I attached the 2nd SSD with Win10 the sound was working properly. Interestingly, with attached headphones I get a proper sound. When I switch to Windows the speakers are working as expected so it's not a hardware issue.

```
Linux notebook 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`alsactl init` gives

```
 Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC233" 
"HDA:10ec0235,1d721501,00100002 HDA:80862809,80860101,00100000" 
"0x1d72" "0x1501"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

I tried the `./alsa-info_alsa-info.sh` script whose output can be fetched under http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=41ca8f63e14ed055a8a45b4dde60a4d0606bfdb1

My user is added to the audio group and and all volume controls in plasma are at the highest level.

Unfortunately I didn't find a proper solution for my problem so any help or ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Pulseaudio? If yes, does the sink show in `pavucontrol`? Correct sink for running application? Everything unmuted that should be unmuted?

Comment: Why are you using Debian 9 instead of Debian 11? Check if this solves your issue (if you don't want to upgrade): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669138/233262

Comment: too simple , remove win10 :D

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to some problems with upgraded packages on Debian. I run into similar problem last month and I also use Debian Stretch.

After several hours of investigation I ran across this Debian bugreport which says that `timidity` daemon may cause the problem because it blocks the sound card:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=901931

You may try to kill the `timidity` as root. On my computer it immediately solves the problem:

```
sudo killall timidity
```

Comment: How would the headphone jack work but the speakers not if this were the issue?

Comment: Only if headphone jack and speakers would be different sound devices in the system and the timidity would block only one of them. It is not very likely, but I don't understand the mechanism why and how bug in timidity blocks sound devices.

Comment: I would be surprised if your solution resolved the OPs issue, but we'll see if they report back.