# No sound on firefox after debian update

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, pipewire

I juste switched from Debian Bullseye to Debian testing. After rebooting, I found out that firefox could not output any sound from video (checked on youtube and twitter).

I checked some videos with Chromium, and I have no issue. MPV video playback or any other application tried (moc, some games, ...) does have sound.

I must say that I don't really understand the linux audio stack and don't know where to look for debugging info. I checked `pavucontrol` input per application, I can see that Firefox is sending an audio output.
But I cannot see any other application.

I think I could have some pipewire/pulseaudio conflict, but I'm not sure to understand what's happening here.
Here is a list of some audio related package I have installed.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep pulse
ii  libpulse-dev:amd64                                          16.1+dfsg1-2                            amd64        PulseAudio client development headers and libraries
ii  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64                               16.1+dfsg1-2                            amd64        PulseAudio client libraries (glib support)
ii  libpulse0:amd64                                             16.1+dfsg1-2                            amd64        PulseAudio client libraries
ii  libpulse0:i386                                              16.1+dfsg1-2                            i386         PulseAudio client libraries
ii  libpulsedsp:amd64                                           16.1+dfsg1-2                            amd64        PulseAudio OSS pre-load library
rc  pipewire-pulse                                              0.3.59-1                                amd64        PipeWire PulseAudio daemon
ii  pulseaudio                                                  16.1+dfsg1-2                            amd64        PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils                                            16.1+dfsg1-2                            amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulsemixer                                                  1.5.1-1                                 all          command-line mixer for PulseAudio with a curses interface

$ dpkg -l | grep pipewire
ii  libpipewire-0.3-0:amd64                                     0.3.59-1                                amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server
ii  libpipewire-0.3-common                                      0.3.59-1                                all          libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - common files
ii  libpipewire-0.3-modules:amd64                               0.3.59-1                                amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - modules
ii  pipewire:amd64                                              0.3.59-1                                amd64        audio and video processing engine multimedia server
ii  pipewire-bin                                                0.3.59-1                                amd64        PipeWire multimedia server - programs
ii  pipewire-media-session                                      0.4.1-4                                 amd64        example session manager for PipeWire
rc  pipewire-pulse
```

Any hint on what to look for to solve this issue ?

Comment: Do you have [plasma-pa installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669138/233262) if you're using KDE (which DE you use should be in your question)?

Comment: I don't have KDE (neither plaspa-pa), I've installed debian with all pre-installed packaged disabled and built my system upon it. My Window Manager is i3, and I launch every application from cli.