# No output or input devices found for audio on Debian/KDE since pulseaudio can't be started ("Failed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix"")

Tags: debian, audio, kde, pulseaudio

On one of my Debian12/KDE machines when clicking on the tray icon for the volume (`plasma-pa`) it just shows "No output or input devices found for audio" so there is no way to make the device play audio. I haven't yet determined the cause.

In `pavucontrol` no output is displayed either. I already tried reinstalling `pulseaudio` (via `--reinstall`) and before trying to restart pulseaudio also tried `pulseaudio -k`. `lspci` does show the soundcard. `systemctl --user status pulseaudio` shows `Active: inactive (dead)`

It seems like the problem is that pulseaudio can't be properly started, when running `pulseaudio`, this is the output:

```
E: [pulseaudio] socket-server.c: bind(): Address already in use
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: D-Bus name org.pulseaudio.Server already taken.
E: [pulseaudio] bluez-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
```

There's no output for `pulseaudio --start` but that doesn't start it either. I had a problem with missing audio after an upgrade two years ago but that was be solved [by upgrading packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/652621/233262) and/or [installing plasma-pa](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/669001/233262) which got lost. I made sure all packages are up to date.

Edit: regarding whether or not pulseaudio is running, `pacmd list-cards` returns `No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon`.
`systemctl --user status pipewire` returns:

```
Active: active (running)
[...]
mod.rt: Can't find org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop. Is xdg-desktop-portal running?
mod.rt: Found session bus but no portal
```

How to get the sound working again?

Comment: No surprise: `E: [pulseaudio] socket-server.c: bind(): Address already in use`: there's already a pulseaudio running

Comment: But you might be barking up the wrong tree! Pulseaudio's functionality is, these days, implemented by pipewire (which is a drop-in replacement, so pavucontrol and every other pulse client continue to work). Maybe you could check `systemctl --user status pipewire`? If that says anything but "Unit pipewire.service could not be found", you have pipewire and want to uninstall pulseaudio, probably.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought that was likely the cause but then why can't I restart it? I also tried quitting it right before with `pulseaudio -k`. I'll add the output of `systemctl --user status pipewire` to the question. Are you saying uninstalling pulseaudio would be enough to get audio back? I don't think just uninstalling it would solve this.

Comment: you're really not using pulseaudio, you're using pipewire (as you should!) and pulse seems to be conflicting with that somehow. I can't promise uninstalling pulseaudio and a reboot can't fix that – but it's what I'd try; pulse at the very least is not positively involved in getting you sound :)

Comment: To be fair, it seems that the problem is that pipewire somehow isn't enumerating your sound devices as sinks. If pipewire is running, you should make sure pulse is not enable (e.g. `systemctl --user disable pulseaudio; sudo systemctl --global disable pulseaudio`). Then after a reboot (just to make things easy), you may want to check `pactl list sinks` and `pgrep -a pulse`. If the former does not list any (non-null) sink, you may want to check `aplay -l`. If the latter shows some `pulseaudio` process (instead of `pipewire-pulse` one), you may want to find out what is starting pulse.

Comment: If `aplay -l` does not list your sound devices, then it's not pipewire itself (or its components) that is having problem, I suppose. If it does, then you may want to share full log of pipewire (and pipewire-pulse, and maybe wireplumber).

Comment: I tried uninstalling and restarting the session and later rebooting but that didn't help and I don't know how it could. I'm leaving it uninstalled so that's still a good hint and found the cause now (see answer). I noticed that even after uninstalling the `pactl` command can still be used which is a main part of [this physical vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/272952/139250) - why is that when pipewire is used, pulseaudio is uninstalled and only pipewire-pulse is running?

Comment: pactl, unlike pacmd, is a program that works via libpulse (the client library), while pipewire-pulse is pretty much a "drop-in replacement" pulse sever. Pipewire only consist of a server side replacement so that all the program that makes use of libpulse can make use of pipewire-pulse without any changes. (pipewire-pulse is kinda like Xwayland.)

Comment: Ah okay, so if for example a code change to limit the speed of sound volume change was implemented in pulseaudio that would also be available in pipewire without requiring some additional changes. Please let me know in case that is false.

Comment: Well, I suppose it depends. If the change is done in the client library, then yes. But if it is implemented in the (original) pulse server, then no. (Btw, I don't really consider the post you linked is legit in terms of idea of vulnerability. One thing that it is IMHO indeed sort of bad is, IIRC, `pactl` allows you set a "gain" in the volume, that is, it can be greater than 100% / "0dB", and I am not sure if it can be configured not to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause now or at least the solution: quitting the qsynth process.

Before asking I noticed that a to me unknown qsynth process is trying to make Internet connection with `sudo lsof -i` but didn't think it was causing this problem and still don't know why it did. `aptitude why qsynth` shows it was installed due to an upgrade of `lutris` (v0.5.14) which depends on `fluidsynth` which recommends this package (v0.9.9-1). It was recently upgraded after changing the lutris repo to from its Debian11 repo (which had a signing key error) to 12. ([Issue here](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/issues/5118))

The strange thing is that I only needed to quit the process once in the process manger (`plasma-systemmonitor` in KDE whose custom shortcut ctrl+shift+esc didn't work anymore btw) and did not need to remove it. I still have it installed but the audio is still working even after quitting the session and logging back in. It doesn't autostart anymore. Another strange thing is that I don't know why lutris would need fluidsynth.

While this problem is solved for now, more information why this occurred and how to prevent it would be useful. Problems like audio getting lost and requiring fiddling around to recover should never occur, especially not on stable Debian.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have pipewire-jack.

Comment: @TomYan More context or info would be good, this just leaves me guessing what it's for / what problem it would have mitigated. In any case, problems like audio getting lost should not occur.

Comment: Well, JACK is another sound API / server that is used mainly by "pro audio" programs (like DAW and whatsoever). Those programs often starts a JACK server upon their own startup. The JACK server will open / grab your sound card when it is started, which prevents pipewire from being able to do so. (Unlike pulse / pipewire, JACK does not release the card when it is "idle". Even if it does, programs that uses different sound APIs / servers will still have conflict when they need to use the card simultaneously. And pipewire also provides a "drop-in replacement" JACK implementation.

Comment: Because pipewire-pulse and pipewire-jack are kinda like proxies / compatibility layers, programs that makes use of either of them will actually be mixed by pipewire behind the scene. In other words, now you have one single program that opens / grabs the card and mixes sound streams into one and sends it to the card. (Btw, my comment in your question isn't exactly true. I don't really know why pipewire does not implement the pulse client libraries but does so for the jack client library.)